# Making JavaDocs available with GitHub, Sonatype Maven repo

Tags: java, open-source, github, javadoc

Although Github provides a nice home for Java open source projects, there are some things that are still missing compared to more mature open source hosting places. I have so far figured out that Sonatype offers Maven repository access for open source projects, which solves one issue; and there are many solutions for user/dev mailing lists.

But one thing I am now trying to resolve is that of publishing automatically generated javadocs for online browsing. Although publishing source jars via Maven helps a bit with IDEs, I still like ability to browse javadocs online without downloading or importing a project. Does anyone know of a good way to achieve this, for projects hosted at Github? (need not be something Github offers, but ideally something that can be automated to happen when release is cut)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

GitHub serves static HTML files that are in the `gh-pages` branch of your repo at `http://your_username.github.com/your_repo/`. In theory, Maven could be made to do the following:

1. Commit the release `pom.xml`.
2. Generate the JavaDocs to a `.gitignore`'d directory (so it would be preserved across branch changes).
3. Checkout the `gh-pages` branch.
4. Replace all of the files in the working directory with that of the directory the JavaDocs were copied to
5. Commit
6. Checkout the original branch.
7. Continue with release...

I'm only two days in to using Maven for a few of my projects so this is way beyond my capabilities. I'd be eager to see this implemented either with existing plugins or a custom plugin.

Comment: Thanks, that's a good idea and could work well enough.

Comment: FWIW, this has worked pretty well, even without more automation. I just do 'mvn install', rename 'target/apidocs' as 'javadoc/[VERSION]', 'git add' commit and that's about it.

Comment: FYI, I'm now using http://khuxtable.github.com/wagon-gitsite/ which FULLY automates site deployments to the `gh-pages` branch.

Comment: For my [jsch-documentation-project](https://github.com/epaul/jsch-documentation), I'm using `git-new-workdir` to have a second working directory with the gh-pages branch, and a symbolic link to put the javadocs into this directory. No automated commit and push, though.

Comment: Doesn't that mean you commit your javadoc files into your repo? I also thought it's bad form to commit generated files.

Comment: Technically, yes, but the `gh-pages` branch is served by GitHub as static files allowing users to access the javadocs in their browser. Since the branch is usually created with a detached history (meaning no common ancestors with your `master` and other branches) it is kept separate from the code.

Comment: I'm sorry for the off-topic but for security reasons GitHub does not allow framing in the `gh-pages` web server. However, javadocs view consists in 3 frames. Did you find any work around?

Comment: Or just make a separate repo holding the docs.

Answer (score 16):

There is now a Maven plugin that can push a directory to a particular branch on githib at: http://github.com/github/maven-plugins.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a shell script to do the git checkout/add/commit/checkout/push as Jake Wharton suggested, and configure Ant or Gradle to run the shell script after it generates the javadoc. I'm not sure this would work with Maven.  Here's an [example shell script](https://github.com/jmkristian/bigFloat/blob/master/publish.sh).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the github pages, creating a static web site then you put your javadoc in a directory and commmit to gh-pages branch.

see the Git hub pages, its simple and useful.

see

http://readwrite.com/2013/11/27/github-pages-explained#awesm=~oII5EQELsqV6S7