# how to create Readme Document automatically in java not from Git hub

Tags: java, readme

I want to create a readme or something similar to javadoc automatically .
My code is already ready and i am finding ways if readme can be created automatically if yes then how.
I don't want readme doc which is created by Git hub.

Comment: the topic you're asking for is markdown creation (.md file). I googled a bit and saw a javadoc to markdown [generator](https://delight-im.github.io/Javadoc-to-Markdown/), maybe there's more. so you'd have the chain java -> javadoc -> markdown

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Display JavaDocs on GitHub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15347808/display-javadocs-on-github)

Comment: @gurioso: Thanks for reply i tried option you mentioned however my code is without javadoc so it is giving me #Documentation as a results.

Comment: @GAK : we are not using git hub and can't upload code on git because of privacy policy.Is there any other way.

Comment: Hm, but how is then the relationship from your java (I assume) code to something that looks like markup? But maybe I understood the question all wrong. If you have no javadoc sections in your code, then it seems to me, there is no way.

Comment: @guriso :I will paste the code sample just for sample:public class ReadExcel {
 
 public static String LoadData() {
 
  try {
   
     
   File fs=new File(AppVariableConstants.TestDataPath);
   FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(fs);
   HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook (fis);
   HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
       int rows; // No of rows
      int cols;
      String KeyHeader;
      String ValueCell=null;
      rows = sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows();
       code sample...}}}

Comment: Ok, how should the readme look like then, departing from this snippet? It is not obvious, there are plenty of ways.

Comment: @guriso: this is actually a automation framework using java.So readme should have how to install it and each function or method details(just like javadoc has for in-build function).Not sure if this is possible or i have to manually create.

Comment: well, @AmrutaPande, I'd also wish to have such kind of generator at hand occasionally. But I'm afraid, there isn't any who can generate user manuals based on code (yet). If there's anybody who can prove me wrong, please do it **now**.

Comment: Is it really a **lot** of documentation, you're talking here about? Like hundreds of pages?

Answer (score 0):

I don´t know if you can do it via java, but there are some amazing tools that help a lot when it comes to generate readme files. Some are Web based like [this one](https://readme.so/editor) and other are web based similar to https://github.com/kefranabg/readme-md-generator